# Create a "clock plot" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, data-visualization

I'm not sure exactly what this kind of chart is called, but I'm going to call it a "clock plot"

Basically I want to use it to visualize events that happen at certain times of day over say the course of a month. The idea is to record the time that this particular event occurs during the day and plot it on the graph. That way at the end of the month, I can visualize the frequency of the events over time. Is something like this even possible in Excel and if so, how could I do it? Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: This can be created either by Pie chart or Radar,,, but the need is some sample data,,  please [Edit] your post & share some sample data with us!

Comment: It's literally just a list of times (military time and AM/PM) with the cell formatting set accordingly. But I'll edit in the morning when I turn my computer on

Comment: Hey @audiFanatic,, or U may check Tableau since Excel does have limit in that regard!!

Comment: Hi, @Jon Peltier I've seen that you have solved many issues related to data visualization,, can't you try this one for the benefit of the community?

Comment: @RajeshS I added the sample data as requested

Comment: I've use Military Time, Event & Pain (since 1 numeric field is required),, other two are Axis value,, and drawn Donut Pie Chart (one single ring,, has segment for time), but not exactly as you have show, since Excel doesn't have any such,, confirm if works for U, then I'll post !

Comment: @Rajesh pain isn't neccesarily something that needs to be there and wasn't my original intention (but would be nice now that you mention it). I just included the entire dataset for completeness. In any case, all I'm really trying to do is visualize what time of day most of the seizures happened. Now that you mention pain level, I suppose I could use a regulatar scatter plot with pain on the X axis and time on the Y. But still this clock thing is an interesting exercise